# How can I create session inside views in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@Session["username"]="shahed";
@Session["password"]="123";
<div style="height:200px;width:500px;background-color:red;">

     <h3>@Session["username"].ToString()</h3>

</div>
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Login")
```

this code throw an exception while creating session in views.But i can create session in action of controller.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it inside a code block

```
@{ Session["username"]="shahed"; }
....
<h3>@Session["username"].ToString()</h3>
```

Comment: Then you should consider accepting the answer to close this out.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not a good idea to set `Session` data in a view you can easily do that.

```
<h2>Login</h2>
@{
    // code block - whole statement evaluate
    Session["username"]="shahed";
    Session["password"]="123";
}
<div style="height:200px;width:500px;background-color:red;">
<h3>@Session["username"].ToString()</h3>
```

The difference from your code is assignments to `Session` are done inside `@{..}` block (C# code) where your version used `@` which computed `Session["username"]` as C# code and the rest (`="shahed"`) as HTML markup - hence no assignment made (and next line throws NRE on `@Session["username"].ToString()` since `Session["username"]` is still `null`).